# Problema de restar cantidades de un producto

Tags: php

Tengo que restar la cantidad de un producto cuando se compra, pero cuando el contador llega a cero, debe mostrar 0, no se como hacerlo y como lo tengo actualmente no funciona

```
$marca=$_POST['marca'];


$consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"SELECT`cantidad` FROM `automovil` WHERE marca = 'Ford'");

if($consulta<='0'){
    echo 'ERROR';
}else{
    $consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"UPDATE `automovil` SET `cantidad` = cantidad -1
WHERE marca ='Ford'");
}
```

segun mi pensamiento, al encontrar que la cantidad sea 0, pues esto muestra un error

Comment: ¿Qué resultado estás obteniendo con este código?

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Qué error muestra? Siempre procura incluir el mensaje de error en tus preguntas. Por otra parte, a tu consulta le falta un espacio: SELECT `cantidad` FROM `automovil` WHERE marca = 'Ford' es la correcta, con un espacio después del SELECT

Comment: Podes explicarnos porque pensas que al encontrar 0 daria error? si la primer consulta no esta verificando eso en ningun lado...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es que lo que guardas en `$consulta` en esta línea:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"SELECT`cantidad` FROM `automovil` WHERE marca = 'Ford'");
```

no es la cantidad que hay, sino el resultado de haber llamado a `query`, que será:

- Un recurso con los datos en caso de haber tenido éxito la consulta
- `FALSE` si hubo un error

Después de haber llamado a `query`, tienes que leer el recurso que ésta devuelve y hacer la comparación con ese valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
$marca=$_POST['marca'];

$consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"SELECT `cantidad` FROM `automovil` WHERE marca = 'Ford'");

#Incializamos a 0 la variable final
$mCantidad=0;
#Compruebas que la consulta no fue errónea
if ($consulta) {
    #Aplicas un método de lectura al resultado
    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
    #Buscas el valor que hay en la columna cantidad
    $mCantidad=$row['cantidad'];    
}

#Supongo que cantidad es numérico, así que quité las comillas
if($mCantidad<=0){
    echo 'ERROR';
}else{
    $consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"UPDATE `automovil` SET `cantidad` = cantidad -1
WHERE marca ='Ford'");
    echo "Había $mCantidad de vehículos y se ha restado 1.";
}
```

---

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Tu código es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Conviene que te documentes sobre ese grave riesgo y que
> implementes consultas preparadas en este caso.

Comment: le agradezco mucho su aporte, me funciono y ahora hace lo que quiero

Comment: @SantiagoQuintin no olvides que si esta respuesta te solucionó el problema, el mejor modo de agradecer es marcarla como aceptada, dado clic en la *palomita* que esta del lado izquierdo